# How to interpret the meaning of "umso mehr" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> X sollte dich nicht betrüben, Y **umso mehr**.
>
> = "X should not pose you any problem – Y (on the other hand) **all the more**."

I have no problem understanding "umso mehr" when it is used in the "je mehr ... , desto/umso mehr" construction. I'm not sure, though, what exactly "umso mehr" means in this specific sentence.

The rather literal translation "all the more" does not seem to make much sense.

Comment: "But Y certainly will" or "which is not at all true for Y" should work.

Comment: This literally means **even more** in this case. The construction plays with the negative statement in the first clause. If it was **even less** (*umso weniger*) it would be similar to the *je X, umso Y*. But the first clause is negative, and the second not "negative", and so the worries you should have about Y *should be even more* than those you **shouldn't** have about X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Y will pose an even bigger problem, it will trouble you even more than X. That is the meaning of "umso mehr". Probably it is not common in english to shorten sentences like Germans do. In German the complete Sentence would read:

> X sollte dich nicht betrüben, aber Y sollte Dich umso mehr betrüben.

And this would be translated (to use your wordings):

> X should not pose you and problem - Y will pose you problems all the more

Answer (score 1):

I would translate your sentence to:

> X muss dich nicht betrüben – Y umso mehr.

Meaning:

> You think X is a problem?
>   It isn't.
>
> You think Y is no problem or a small one?
>   It's a big one.